# Cannot read property 'prev' in React Native

Tags: react-native

[image]

> here I have attached image of my error.My app worked properly.Then without any code change I got this issue.tried different methods.but could not solved this.I cleared watchman also.But I was not worked for me.Any one can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

> Finally found the solution.
>
> To resolve try the following:
>
> 1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
> 2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
> 3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start --reset-cache`.